# Not able to call WCF from Windows 2008 server

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am using WCF service hosted on IIS and it works fine from Win7 machine, but when called from Windows 2008 it is throwing the exception

> The caller was not authenticated by the service

I checked the event log and got the following message

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/09/2013 12:00:05 
Event time (UTC): 11/09/2013 11:00:05 
Event ID: 4a6a7d25f00b40f189815e9a316406d9 
Event sequence: 67 
Event occurrence: 2 
Event detail code: 0
```

Regards,
Nabin

Comment: You'll need to tell us a lot more for us to be able to help!! Show us some configs! How have you set up your services on the server side? What bindings do you use? How are you trying to call that service? Show us the client-side config!

Comment: Do you use some kind of impersonification ? I remember reading something on the fact that it works on the latest version of windows but not on the older.